# async.js and series issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization, async.js

Try to run fetch after connect. Fetch is faster than connect, and in console I am getting fetch error because it returns result faster than connection done. But in documentation of async series is a tool to run second function after first returns result.Settimeouts saves situation, but its not beautifull. How can I wait, when all done without promises?

```
var bets = [];
async.series([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            connect();
            callback(null, 'one');
        },1)
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            fetch_last_30();
            callback(null, 'two');
        },2000)
    }
]);
```

UPD
my connect function

```
function connect(){
    var url = "https://api....../login";
    /* connect to site and get access_token to access other api*/
    $.post(
        url,
        {username: "000", password : "000"},
        function(data){
            access_token = data["access_token"];
            console.log(data["access_token"]);
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to not call the callback until the `connect()` call completes its asynchronous work.  That's the only way that the async library can do its job.  Since `connect()` is asynchronous, it likely has a callback itself that you can use to know when it is actually done.

Furthermore, you shouldn't need the `setTimeout()` calls at all if you use the async library properly.

Conceptually, you would like something like this where the `connect()` function calls a passed in callback when it finishes its async operation:

```
var bets = [];
async.series([
    function(callback){
        connect(function() {
            callback(null, 'one');
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        fetch_last_30();
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
]);
```

While, I'd would personally find promises a better solution here for sequencing two operations, you could change your `connect()` function to this:

```
function connect(callback){
    var url = "https://api....../login";
    /* connect to site and get access_token to access other api*/
    $.post(
        url,
        {username: "000", password : "000"},
        function(data){
            access_token = data["access_token"];
            console.log(data["access_token"]);
            callback(data);
        }
    )
}
```

---

Here's a version using promises instead of the async library:

```
function connect(callback){
    var url = "https://api....../login";
    /* connect to site and get access_token to access other api*/
    return $.post(url, {username: "000", password : "000"}).then(function(data){
       access_token = data["access_token"];
       console.log(data["access_token"]);
       return data;
    });
}

connect().then(function(data) {
    fetch_last_30();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can detect connection callback, but can't understand how to do it in async. Cycle while-if may be?

Comment: @user3003873 - can you give the `connect()` function a callback that is called when it completes?  You can't while/if in Javascript to wait for an async operation to complete.  Due to Javascript's single threaded nature, that will not work.  Please expose the code behind the `connect()` function if you want more help.

Comment: Thanks! My js understanding became better!